# MPI.File usage: normal file writing vs MPI.File

Tags: file-io, mpi

If I have individual files for each process, does it make any difference if i write into those files using normal file pointer or writing using MPI.File?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using simple contiguous i/o operations?  no, no difference.

If you are using MPI datatype (to describe memory) and/or MPI file views (to describe structure or some other non-contiguous file access), then it's possible the MPI implementation has some kind of noncontiguous i/o operation (e.g. data sieving, list i/o, datatype i/o)

Comment: Follow up question: can we measure the memory used by each mpi process?  [ReF:  **you are using MPI datatype (to describe memory)**]

Comment: There are ways to do this, but nothing in the MPI standard.  you would profile memory the same way you would profile a serial application.